# Error running shell command with subprocess.check_call()

Tags: python, linux, subprocess, rpyc

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import rpyc
conn = rpyc.classic.connect(r"xx.xx.xx.xx")
s = conn.modules.subprocess.check_output(['file',u'`which dd`'])
print s
```

Output is:

```
`which dd`: cannot open ``which dd`' (No such file or directory)  

Process finished with exit code 0
```

When I execute manually on the command prompt it gives me proper output :

```
/bin/dd: symbolic link to /bin/dd.coreutils
```

Is there any Unicode error in my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It runs on the command prompt. But if you will call it through the `subprocess` (so will be with `conn.modules.subprocess`), it will give you error as:

```
>>> subprocess.check_call(['file', '`which python`'])
`which python`: cannot open ``which python`' (No such file or directory)
```

Because in shell, this will be executed as:

```
 mquadri$ file '`which python`'
`which python`: cannot open ``which python`' (No such file or directory)
```

But you want to run it as:

```
mquadri$ file `which python`
/usr/bin/python: Mach-O universal binary with 2 architectures
/usr/bin/python (for architecture i386):    Mach-O executable i386
/usr/bin/python (for architecture x86_64):  Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64
```

In order to make the above command run, pass it as string to `check_call` with `shell=True` as:

```
>>> subprocess.check_call('file `which python`', shell=True)
/usr/bin/python: Mach-O universal binary with 2 architectures
/usr/bin/python (for architecture i386):    Mach-O executable i386
/usr/bin/python (for architecture x86_64):  Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64
```